# flask_dance + Google Search Console API searchAnalytics

Tags: python, flask, oauth, google-search-console

I'm currently testing Google Search Console API and Flask Dance to do the oauth stuff.

It works great for getting the /sites, but i get an

> ValueError: View function did not return a response

if i try to query searchAnalytics with /search

According to https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query#try-it it must be POST + additonal data. e.g.:

```
json={'startDate':'2017-11-01','endDate':'2017-12-01'}
```

In https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ it works like this but with flask dance sadly not. any ideas?

```
import os
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
from raven.contrib.flask import Sentry

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
sentry = Sentry(app)
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("FLASK_SECRET_KEY", "supersekrit")
app.config["GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"] = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID")
app.config["GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"] = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET")
google_bp = make_google_blueprint(scope=["profile", "email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters"])
app.register_blueprint(google_bp, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "BlA BLA"

@app.route("/sites")
def sites():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    resp = google.get("/webmasters/v3/sites")
    siteEntry = resp.json()["siteEntry"]
    result = ""
    for site in siteEntry:
        result = result + site["siteUrl"] + "</br>"
    return result

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    resp = google.post("/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fzrce.eu/searchAnalytics/query", json={'startDate':'2017-11-01','endDate':'2017-12-01'})
    print(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

All API routes should always return something even if its an empty response.

Simply return a response, it can be  `""` or `resp`.

Comment: Tested it without success. I think the route is separated from the stuff flask dance is doing. The route should just define the output URL I think.

Comment: Even if you use a `POST` method you still need to return a response (ie: result or confirmation ). I've updated my answer!